# Android shared element return transition to previous activity

Tags: android, transition, android-transitions

I have 3 activities: `ActivityA` --> `ActivityB` --> `ActivityC`.

I have a shared element transition from `ActivityA` to `ActivityB`, a thumbnail that grows to become the background of `ActivityB`. If I hit "back" while in `ActivityB`, the return shared element transition is called: the background view shrinks back to its thumbnail position in `ActivityA`.

If I don't hit "back", `ActivityB` loads some data, navigates to `ActivityC` and finishes.

`ActivityC` has a view that is identical to the one shared between `ActivityA` and `ActivityB` (with the same `transitionName` too). When I hit "back" from `ActivityC`, I'd like for the return shared element transition to be called in the same way it's called when hitting "back" from `ActivityB` to `ActivityA` - for the background to shrink back into its thumbnail position in `ActivityA`.

**Navigation code:**

```
/* thumbnailView is the view in ActivityA that grows into ActivityB */
void navigateToActivityB(Activity activityA, View thumbnailView) {

    // Build options
    List<Pair<View, String>> pairs = new ArrayList<>();
    pais.add(Pair.create(thumbnailView, "thumbnailTransition"));
    Bundle options = ActivityOptionsCompat.makeSceneTransitionAnimation(activityA, pairs.toArray(new Pair[pairs.size()])).toBundle();

    // Navigate
    Intent intent = new Intent(activityA, ActivityB.class);
    ActivityCompat.startActivity(activityA, intent, options);
}

/**
 * Here I don't have thumbnailView anymore (since it's in ActivityA
 * and I'm coming from ActivityB, so I can't include it in the
 * shared element pairs.
 */
void navigateToActivityC(Activity activityB) {

    // Build options - I wish I could use the pairs but I don't know how
    // List<Pair<View, String>> pairs = new ArrayList<>();
    // pais.add(Pair.create(thumbnailView, "thumbnailTransition"));
    Bundle options = ActivityOptionsCompat.makeSceneTransitionAnimation(activityB).toBundle();

    // Navigate
    Intent intent = new Intent(activityB, ActivityC.class);
    ActivityCompat.startActivity(activityB, intent, options);
}
```

**ActivityB**

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    TransitionInflater inflater = TransitionInflater.from(context);
    getWindow().setSharedElementEnterTransition(inflater.inflateTransition(R.transition.shared_element_enter));
    getWindow().setSharedElementReturnTransition(inflater.inflateTransition(R.transition.shared_element_return));
```

**ActivityC**

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    TransitionInflater inflater = TransitionInflater.from(context);

    // This transition doesn't work :(
    getWindow().setSharedElementReturnTransition(inflater.inflateTransition(R.transition.shared_element_return));
```

EDIT:

It's worth mentioning that I made a test where I kept the thumbnail view from `ActivityA` in some static variable. Then when navigating to `ActivityC` I generated the `options` argument with this view in the same way I did in `navigateToActivityB`, and in this case the return transition worked. This is not a viable solution though, both because it's very bad to save views in this way (but I have no other way to pass views around between activities), and because it caused some strange artifacts (a weird flicker of the thumbnail in `ActivityB`).

Comment: Hi, I am stuck in a similar situation. I use the reorder flag to start activity A from activity C. I have a shared element from B->C and want to use it back in Activity A. The below-listed solution is not working for me. It could be great if you could help me out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the [documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/Window.html#setSharedElementReturnTransition(android.transition.Transition)) states

> #### setSharedElementReturnTransition
>
> Sets the Transition that will be used for shared elements transferred back to a calling Activity.

Here you finishing the calling activity `ActivityB`. Which means it is not returning to calling activity. So Transition is not displayed.

You probably wanted to use [setSharedElementExitTransition](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/Window.html#setSharedElementExitTransition(android.transition.Transition)).

Comment: You're right that it's not returning to the calling activity, but it's still hitting "back" which means return transition and not exit (exit transition is what happens when we navigate to a new activity).

Comment: Please see a relevant edit to the original question.

Comment: Ok. Does [setReturnTransition](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/Window.html#setReturnTransition(android.transition.Transition)) work?

Comment: If that doesn't work, do something like this - when starting C from B start using `startActivityForResult` and `onActivityResult` finish it.

Comment: Interesting solution, thanks! It's not ideal though because even though `onActivityResult` gets called before `onResume`, I still see `ActivityB` briefly before it disappears (with the correct return transition). Any idea why?

Comment: It is because the activity is still resumed but `onResume` is yet to be called.

Comment: Another solution is to add `android:noHistory="true"` in manifest on `ActivityB`. I m not sure whether it would work or not. It remove the activity from the stack as soon as it user leaves it.

Comment: I tried `noHistory`, didn't work unfortunately. Is there any way you know of to finish the activity before it's shown?

Comment: No. I m sorry, I don't know any other way to finish an activity.

Comment: Hi @ShreyashSSarnayak , I am stuck in a similar situation mentioned above. I use the reorder flag to start activity A from activity C. I have a shared element from B->C and want to use it back in Activity A. The above-listed solution is not working for me. It could be great if you could help me out.

Comment: @KailashChivhe It's been long time since I worked on this. Sorry, I can't help you on this.